# AD query Powershell and Export to txt file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can someone help me?

I have to create a `.txt` file with the following format:

```
user("SamAccountName","GivenName Surname"){}
```

I'm able to create just this:

```
#Get AD Users Info
cls
$SamAccountName = New-Item 'c:\SamAccountName.txt' -type file -Force

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName | 
    select -First 15 | Sort-Object SamAccountName |
         Format-Table SamAccountName | Out-File $SamAccountName


$content = Get-Content $SamAccountName
$content | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd() } | where {$_ -ne ""} | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Set-Content $SamAccountName


#Write quotes (make it nice and readable!)
$ACTIVEDIRECTORY = New-Item 'c:\ACTIVEDIRECTORY.lst' -type file -Force

Clear-Content $ACTIVEDIRECTORY

$quotes= '"'

(Get-Content $SamAccountName) |     
    ForEach-Object {Add-Content $ACTIVEDIRECTORY "$quotes$_$quotes"}

    Get-Content $ACTIVEDIRECTORY
```

This give me this result:

```
"GivenName"
"GivenName"
"GivenName"
```

Comment: Read through your code.... Do you know what ever part is doing and why, or is this simply copy and paste? Use comments and make a plan on how to achieve your goal. To answer this, I would need to rewrite the whole code. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @notjustme about your question being a mess, but I'll throw an answer out there anyway.

Your first problem is how you set these two variables. They end up being objects, but you're trying to use them like file paths.

```
$SamAccountName = "c:\SamAccountName.txt"
$ACTIVEDIRECTORY = "c:\ACTIVEDIRECTORY.lst"
```

This will get you a comma separated list of your users, which is (sort of) what part of your code is doing.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object SamAccountName, GivenName, SurName -First 15 | Sort-Object SamAccountName | Export-Csv $SamAccountName -NoTypeInformation
```

This will get you the list of users with the string format you specified at the top, which is odd, but whatever.

```
Import-Csv $SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {"user(`"$($_.SamAccountName)`",`"$($_.GivenName) $($_.Surname)`"){}"} | Out-File $ACTIVEDIRECTORY
```

Comment: Good job! I guess you deciphered all that correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't try it out myself at the moment but... from experience...

```
-properties * | select SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname
```

Should get ya in the ballpark.

Re-read your code a few times and well... it seems a mess to be honest. You state what you wanna accomplish and then there's a crud-load of other stuff that make close to no sense in this case. Maybe I'm just too tired, I'll check back in the morning and edit/delete if needed.

Allright, re-read a few more times and the headache is given but still...

In general I'd like to advise you (or anyone, really) if Powershell get's confuzzling to break it down in easily processable pieces.

For the users;

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like '*' } -Properties * | select SamAccountName, Givenname, Surname
```

For the output;

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    '("{0}""{1}{2}"' -f $user.SamAccountName, $user.GivenName, $user.Surname
}
```

Unfortunatly I have no way to try this out myself at the moment but it should be in the ballpark... if you end up getting some errors, lemme know and I'm sure I can guide ya through it. I'm not 100% sure about them single and doublequotes in this particular case... I'd have to try it out.